How to link Android phone emulator to external bluetooth device (not emulated)
I am developing a Phone app with Android Studio and I need the app to connect to an external bluetooth device (e.g. Garmin watch).  I do not have a real Android phone, so am using an emulator.  I would like my emulator to connect to the external (real) BLE device, so that I can test functionality.
My question is similar to this question, but I want to actively test with a real BLE input.
I think that Google Bumble would be helpful here, such as the example code in this link:
$ bumble-hci-bridge android-netsim:_:8877,mode=controller usb:0

But with a watch, for example, I do not have a USB dongle to designate as the controller-transport-spec (2nd argument).  How can I connect my emulator to the BLE device using a Windows laptop with Bluetooth device?
